# Examples of non semisimple module

Tags: modules

I've seen following definition: an $R$-module $M$ is semisimple if every submodule of $M$ has a complement.

Does anyone have example of a module which is not semisimple in $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{C}[t]$ and $\mathbb{C}[\mathbb{Z}]$?

I think $\mathbb{Z}$ is the module which is not semisimple in $\mathbb{Z}$. But I couldn't find module which is not semisimple in  $\mathbb{C}[t]$ or $\mathbb{C}[\mathbb{Z}]$. Does anyone have an example?

Comment: Maybe you and your classmates can pool your questions instead of duplicating?  I'm noticing this was the third version of the question in the span of two days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fact**.
*For every nontrivial submodule $N$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ we have $N\cap 2\mathbb{Z}\neq 0$.*

**Proof.** Indeed, for every nontrivial submodule $N\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ pick $n\in N\setminus \{0\}$. Then $2n\in 2\mathbb{Z}\cap N$.

In particular, $2\mathbb{Z}\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ has no complement.

For $\mathbb{C}[t]$ pick $t\cdot \mathbb{C}[t]\subseteq \mathbb{C}[t]$ and use analogical argument as for $\mathbb{Z}$.

It remains to check the result for group algebra $\mathbb{C}[\mathbb{Z}]$. Note that $\mathbb{C}[\mathbb{Z}]\cong \mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]$. Pick $(t-1)\cdot \mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]\subseteq \mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]$ and use analogical argument as for $\mathbb{Z}$.